# Parse json without full path

Tags: c#, json

I want to parse json without entering the path to it:

I have https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=tf2%20Hats%20Summer%20Shades%20site:wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/ , How can i get the string from unescapedUrl?

How can i make it without the path, so i have those [ and {, How can i use it.

My code is

```
        string itemname = "Hat with no name";
        var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
        var json = webClient.DownloadString("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=tf2%20Hats" + itemname + "%20site:wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/");
        Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject o = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json);
        string HatURL = (string)o["responseData"]["results"]["unescapedUrl"];
```

But then i get an error...

Thanks for your help,

-Krypton

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking?

Comment: First of all provided JSON is not valid. And it's not clear what are trying to achieve.

Comment: I agree the comments above. 1) You need to do more research 2) Fix your JSON 3) You can search for Json serialize/deserialize. There are a lot of libraries out there that will help you parse this.

Comment: That is broken, thus there are no correct answers. If you mean to auto-correct: find and replace "([a-z])\[" with "\1: [". If that's inside quotes, write a full parser (not as hard as it sounds).

Comment: You have a list of objects that contain `unescapedUrl` property. And you are trying to get only one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DescendantsAndSelf()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_DescendantsAndSelf.htm) to find all descendant properties with the `"unescapedUrl"` name.  But since `DescendantsAndSelf()` is only defined for `JContainer` I find it helpful to [extend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) it to `JToken`:

```
    public static IEnumerable<JToken> DescendantsAndSelf(this JToken node)
    {
        if (node == null)
            return Enumerable.Empty<JToken>();
        var container = node as JContainer;
        if (container != null)
            return container.DescendantsAndSelf();
        else
            return new [] { node };
    }
```

Then use it like:

```
        var root = JToken.Parse(json);

        var query = root.DescendantsAndSelf().OfType<JProperty>().Where(p => p.Name == "unescapedUrl");
        foreach (var property in query)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(property.Path);
            var url = (string)property;
            // process the unescapedUrl somehow.
        }
```

You will see that there are actually four `"unescapedUrl"` properties in an array of results:

```
responseData.results[0].unescapedUrl
responseData.results[1].unescapedUrl
responseData.results[2].unescapedUrl
responseData.results[3].unescapedUrl
```

The syntax to access element `i` of the array would be:

```
root["responseData"]["results"][i]["unescapedUrl"]
```

But it would probably be better to access them with Linq:

```
var firstUrl = (string)query.FirstOrDefault();
```